# maximum number of process in linux with paging

Tags: linux, paging

I heard that maximum number of process(tasks) in linux is calculated with

"number of threads = total virtual memory / (stack size*1024*1024)"

however, I am curious that since page tables can not be paged out

and every process needs it's own page tables(including page directory)

I think this can be a factor to limit number of process in OS.

am I correct or wrong?

Comment: from the FAQ, "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."

Comment: This is an actual problem which I am facing these days, I need to know detailed relationship between paging and process allocation. and I think this is an answerable question...

Answer (score 0):

According to the book [IA-64 Linux Kernel: Design and Implementation, chapter 4.3 Page Tables](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=29961&seqNum=3), you are correct.